# Can someone help me with the steps to fix the imports in this contract so that it will compile?

Tags: import

When I clone a contract from a repo from github on vscode (take, e.g., the one linked below), and I try to compile it, I always get errors with the imports...the imports will have stuff like @uniswapv3 and then there will be a remppings.txt file that says @uniswapv3=[CORRECT FILE PATH], but these remappings never seem to work me. I can manually fix them all, but a lot of times that is a lot of work.

So my question is, when I clone a repo like the one linked below, what are the steps I need to take so that the imports work? I tried putting the remappings into foundry.toml as well but no dice. I need step by step instructions.

[Here is the contract I was trying to compile](https://github.com/code-423n4/2023-11-panoptic/tree/main/contracts)